# I am getting segmentation fault while using Morris algorithm for inorder traversal of a binary tree

Tags: c++, binary-tree, inorder

The question link was this: [Inorder Traversal (GFG)](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/inorder-traversal/1)
I referred the geeksforgeeks article that had the same code but in void function. I modified it to fit the question. Now I am getting segmentaion fault and I don't know why.
The GFG article: [Inorder Tree Traversal without recursion and without stack!](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inorder-tree-traversal-without-recursion-and-without-stack/)

```
vector<int> inOrder(Node* root) {
    // Your code here
    vector<int>ans;
    Node* current = root;
    Node* pre;
    
    if(!root){return ans;}
    
    while(current){
        if(!root->left){
            ans.push_back(current->data);
            current = current->right;
        }
        else{
            pre = current->left;
            while(pre->right && (pre->right != current)){pre = pre->right;}
            if(!pre->right){
                pre->right = current;
                current = current->left;
            }
            else{
                pre->right = NULL;
                ans.push_back(current->data);
                current = current->right;
            }
        }
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Comment: First of all welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mre], and how to [edit] your question to improve it.

Comment: As for your problem, what does your debugger tell you when you use it to catch the crash? Where in your code does it happen? What are the values of all variables at the time and point of the crash? And have you tried to step through your code in the debugger while monitoring variables, all while you draw and redraw the tree as you perform operations on it?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude look up "morris traversal"

Comment: You have not copied the code correctly, there is at least one typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following condition is wrong:

```
if(!root->left){
```

This will make the *same* check in each iteration. It should relate to the *current* node:

```
if(!current->left){
```